# stop tiling on body tag in Outlook

Tags: html, css, outlook, html-email

I'm using a background image on a body tag for an emailer but when I test it in Outlook it is tiling x and y.

Is there a way to stop this from happening?

```
<body style="background-repeat:no-repeat" bgColor=#ffffff      
      background="http://www.bla.com/bla/twc/email-bg.jpg">
```

I have also tried:

- `background-repeat:no-repeat no-repeat;`
- specifying width and height

Comment: are you using word rendering or html rendering?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `style="background-image: url(http://www.bla.com/bla/twc/email-bg.jpg); background-repeat:no-repeat"`?

Comment: Its html rendering. When using style="Background-image" it wont show at all in outlook.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Full Width Backgrounds on Outlook '07/'10/'13](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23280715/full-width-backgrounds-on-outlook-07-10-13)

Answer (score 0):

CSS backgrounds are not supported by all mail clients. I would suggest not using this feature at all.

See: http://newcampaignmon.cachefly.net/assets/files/css/campaign-monitor-guide-to-css-in-email-sept-2011.pdf

Comment: oups, you have here a dead link ;)